# Как на Windows API читать файл с отключенным кешированием (например нужно сделать бенчмарк SSD)?

Tags: файлы, winapi, кэширование

1. Как на Windows API читать файл с отключенным кешированием (напримсер нужно сделать бенчмарк SSD)?
2. Как открыть файловый дескриптор, с режимом отключенного кеширования в ОЗУ?
3. Как удалить файл произвольный из кеша "mapped files" (которые видят программы от SysInternals), и запретить его кешировать повторно?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: 1,2 - у функции CreateFile есть все опции для этого